# How can I get only one row per record in master table?

Tags: sql, firebird, pivot

it is possible to get only one row per record in a multitable query?

I have this three tables:

### APPLES

```
ID | APPLE
----------
1  | RED
2  | YELLOW
3  | GREEN
```

### FARMS

```
ID  | FARM
--------------------
B1  | GEORGE'S FARM
B2  | JOHN'S FARM
```

### FARM_APPLES

```
FARM  | APPLE
---------------
B1    | 1
B1    | 2
B1    | 3
B2    | 1
B3    | 3
```

With this tables I need this result:

```
FARM_NAME | APPLE_1 | APPLE_2 | APPLE_3
----------------------------------------
B1        | 1       | 2       | 3
B2        |1        |         | 3
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT

Thanks both OMG Ponies and Bill, I'll try both of your solutions, just one last thing, its possible to get this result:

```
FARM          | RED | YELLOW | GREEN
-------------------------------------
GEORGE'S FARM | YES |  YES   |  YES
JOHN's FARM   | YES |  NO    |  YES
```

Comment: Lookup up 'pivot' and 'outer join'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firebird 2.0 supports the CASE expression](http://www.janus-software.com/fbmanual/manual.php?book=psql&topic=56), so you can use:

```
  SELECT fa.farm AS farm_name,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fa.apple = 1 THEN fa.apple ELSE NULL END AS apple_1,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fa.apple = 2 THEN fa.apple ELSE NULL END AS apple_2,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fa.apple = 3 THEN fa.apple ELSE NULL END AS apple_3,
    FROM FARM_APPLES fa
GROUP BY fa.farm
```

Comment: Thanks OMG Ponies, I'll try this when am at home

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT F.ID AS FARM_NAME,
  A1.APPLE AS APPLE_1,
  A2.APPLE AS APPLE_2,
  A3.APPLE AS APPLE_3
FROM FARMS AS F
LEFT OUTER JOIN FARM_APPLES AS A1 ON F.ID = A1.FARM AND A1.APPLE = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN FARM_APPLES AS A2 ON F.ID = A2.FARM AND A2.APPLE = 2
LEFT OUTER JOIN FARM_APPLES AS A3 ON F.ID = A3.FARM AND A3.APPLE = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, seems interesting, I'll try this when am at home.